# Why does the HOME variable have different values during startup

Tags: bash, startup, dot-files

I put the code `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin"` in my .profile file. Then, after startup, if I type in `echo $PATH` it will print out `/home/.local/bin`

However, if I run `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin` after start up and try `echo $PATH` it will instead print out `/home/[my username]/.local/bin` instead.

So the HOME variable changes at some point from `/home` to `/home/[my username]`. Why is this? Does the HOME variable get altered by the OS during/after startup? It's very strange, and makes setting up dotfiles more arcane. If it helps, I'm using mint as my distro, and bash as the shell.

Comment: What else is happening to your `PATH` variable in `~/.profile`?  Are you even using a shell that reads that file? (`bash`, for example, does not read `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` exists, and `zsh` avoids both of these for `~/.zprofile`.) Does your shell use some other files in your home directory, such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`? Do these modify the value of `PATH` too? Consider updating your question with information about what shell you are using and also include `~/.profile` and any other shell startup files. This would make it possible for us to test your setup and answer properly.

Comment: And pelase double check what you've written there. Are you _sure_ that you put in `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin"` (and not `PATH="/home/.local/bin"`) and then `echo $PATH` returns `/home/.local/bin`?

Comment: I've never seen a system where `HOME` would change after logging in. And `HOME` would never be set to `/home`. This has to be a bug in your own dot files. And you need to post the complete files ([enough to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to get specific help.

Comment: You (normally) have one directory called `/home` each user except root has a sub-directory of this -  `/home/username` - this sub-directory is what $HOME is normally preset to. Hence, each user has a different $HOME directory and by abuse of language, `/home/username` is referred to as your "home" directory. But you can refer to it as `~/` if you wish.

Comment: @JeremyBoden every user has a home directory.  It's not an abuse of language to call it that, it's an accurate description of what it is.  Not every home dir is under /home, that's just an arbitrary location that is very commonly used as the parent dir for user home dirs.  A user's home directory can be anywhere on the system (or on another system, via NFS or similar).

Comment: I was trying to distinguish between the /home directory and a typical location of a users $HOME.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'
Here are the dotfiles that seem to be relevant, but the total list of dotfiles on my machine are: .profile, .bashrc, .bash_history, .bash_logout, .dmrc, .gtkrc-2.0, ..gtkrc-xfce. I have no idea which ones are important or actually get run in this scenario, so tell me if I picked the wrong ones to show.
[.profile](https://pastebin.com/a28ZjQFE)
[.bashrc](https://pastebin.com/Zve6HYsb)

@terdon
I made sure, and yeah, it's definitely `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin"`

Comment: Your `.profile` adds both `$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/caara/.local/bin` to `PATH`. What is the complete output of `echo "$PATH"` in a terminal? And `echo "$HOME"`? It looks like your home directory is misconfigured to be `/home` instead of `/home/caara`. Check `getent passwd $(whoami)` (assuming you're running Linux).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you for responding! `echo "$HOME"` returns `/home/caara`, while `echo "$PATH"` returns `/home/caara/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` The original line adding `$HOME/.local/bin` to `PATH` doesn't seem to execute or it'd be included twice in `PATH`. I think it's because it's not configured correctly by default, but I'm not sure. I've changed very little on this machine, and I'm not sure what it could be.